# Maps bug: Markers shifting all over the place when switching view angles. Fix?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Google Javascript Maps API 3.5

Basic issue is that if you have a marker that is over a fixed landmark like a fire hydrant in the overhead view, then you switch to 45 degree view, the marker no longer shows on top of the hydrant. And vice versa (position the marker in 45 degree view then switch to overhead).

To reproduce:

See sample here: [www.zingjet.com/maptest.html](http://www.zingjet.com/maptest.html)

-Create a basic Google Maps web page with a draggable marker. With initial marker/map position over an area with 45 degree imagery available: (try: 33.501472920248354, -82.01948559679795). I'm not certain it shows this problem for all areas so try that point to start.

-Make sure you are zoomed in near the max and in Satellite view

-Turn off 45 degree imagery

-Position marker over fixed point (corner of sidewalk, house chimney,
   etc)

-change to 45 degree view.

-Note that marker position is shifted

-Try rotating the 45 degree and see how marker shifts relative to
   original point on image.

-Switch back to overhead and marker is in original spot.

**Why its a problem**:
Don't know what to trust. What view shows the accurate position for that marker? Can't create web pages that allow people to position markers in one view and see them in another. Major inconsistencies.

Comment: Have you got code sample or jsFiddle?

Comment: sample is here: www.zingjet.com/maptest.html

Comment: I think it could be something wrong with this particular map - if you put marker on this map from [documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/aerial-rotation) everything works as expected

Comment: @hamczu: The one you show doesn't have the effect in some areas, but it is still there. I repositioned your map to be over the park to the south west of the city and was able to reproduce the issue. Basically I don't think Google is doing any math here to reposition markers over tilted maps. That is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I think Google doesn't recalculate position of anything and in most cases it works just fine. It seems that maps in your tested location aren't prepared properly. Maybe you can check this shift and move all object manually but I think it'll be a lot of work.

Comment: @hamczu: sorry to be a pest, but I'm posting the question because I don't think it works just fine, and I have a lot of experience with this (that's why I'm posting the question). This has nothing to do with that one map location, but has to do with thousands of map locations. Anyway, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I think it is very good, interesting question! But if this problem depends on Google Maps API bug then there is no easy/clean solution - so you must use dirty hacks ;) btw. Can you add some locations with correct and incorrect positions - this may be related to the elevation?

Comment: please provide the full code, you can't ask us to reproduce it, you should at least provide a code example.

Comment: @aSeptik: Edited the question to add a sample page. Nothing really to see in the source, its just a map with a draggable marker.

Comment: @Fraggle: i have updated one more time with little fix on latlng that was causing some issue and redefined delta...

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED 2**

> - **demo:** http://bit.ly/IhpeBu

```
        var map, marker, overlay, latlng, zoom = 20;
        function initialize() {
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.501472920248354, -82.01948559679795);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom : zoom,
                center : latlng,
                tilt : 0,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
            overlay.draw = function() {
            };
            overlay.onRemove = function() {
            };
            overlay.setMap(map);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : latlng,
                map : map,
                draggable : true,
                title : "Hello World!"
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
                zoom = map.getZoom();
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
                overlay.setMap(map);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(evt) {
                var tilt = map.getTilt();
                latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(evt.latLng.lat(), evt.latLng.lng());
                if(tilt === 45) {
                    var projection = overlay.getProjection();
                    var latlng2pixel = projection.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getPosition());

                    var delta = 0;
                    switch(zoom) {
                        case 20:
                            delta = 45;
                            break;
                        case 19:
                            delta = 12;
                            break;
                        case 18:
                            delta = 4;
                            break;
                    }
                    latlng = projection.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(latlng2pixel.x, (latlng2pixel.y + delta )));
                }
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilt_changed', function() {
                var tilt = map.getTilt();
                if(tilt === 45) {
                    var delta = 0;
                    switch(zoom) {
                        case 20:
                            delta = 65;
                            break;
                        case 19:
                            delta = 32;
                            break;
                        case 18:
                            delta = 16;
                            break;
                    }
                    var projection = overlay.getProjection();
                    var latlng2pixel = projection.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getPosition());
                    var pixel2latlng = projection.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(latlng2pixel.x, (latlng2pixel.y - delta )));
                    marker.setPosition(pixel2latlng);
                } else {
                    marker.setPosition(latlng);
                }
            });
        }
```

**NOTES:** 
the code above work as follow:

1. Apply a custom overlay to use the;
   `google.maps.MapCanvasProjection object` <sup>[doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=it-IT#MapPanes)</sup>
2. Find the position in pixel of the marker;
3. Add to the `y` ( top = lng ) the 45 degrees ( 45 pixel at zoom 20 ) plus `20` pixel of the marker icon height ( x remain always unvaried since the degrees change is a simple optical illusion ;) );
4. Convert those pixel position to a valid latlng position;
5. observe wheter the `tilt` method change from `0` to `45` and viceversa and act accordingly by setting the new coordinates.

Comment: This is pretty good. Doesn't work if I rotate the view in 45 degree mode. But gives me something to work with. Although that 65 value might change for different map locations, different markers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you are going to have to do likely is to hack it. As far as google is concerned there is likely no error and the point on the map "appears" in a different place because the 45 degree view changes the perspective on the map, and thus how a discrete lat long will physically appear on the map (similiar things can happen when the zoom changes). What you need to do is figure out what that delta is between the views and then hook the "tilt_changed" event and adjust your marker appropriately. One good easy way to learn the delta is to hook the "dblclick" event to alert to you the latlng your mouse is on:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'dblclick', function(MouseEvent){
        alert(MouseEvent.latLng.lat()+" "+MouseEvent.latLng.lng());
    }); 
// make sure you disable the maps default zoom on double click 
//or choose a different event or it will get annoying :)
```

and then dblclick the screen where the marker "should be" and create a function that adjusts the marker accordingly. In theory you may be able to define a function that works on any angle so that all you have to do is pass every marker's position through the function on tilt_changed. Let me know if this is a good start for you :)

Comment: Keep in mind I need this to work for any map, and to handle rotated views (click on 45 degree, then rotate the map). Google should really be handling this. If you have the math to change the markers please post. THanks.